# SQL - When deleting a number value in the middle. How do I CHANGE all numbers to be in order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, workbench

Example:

there are 3 different number values:

1
2
3

I delete the 2 leaving myself with 1 and 3. How do I change the numbers so that the 3 becomes 2?

1 3 -> 1 2

Keep in mind that I have many numbers so I would like to change them all at once and not one by one. That would take alot of time. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, If those numbers are Id's, then you shouldn't do that. This is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are simple position codes and you wanted to you could do

```
delete from mytable where position=2
update mytable set position=position-1 where position>2
```

If they are id's for something, then this would be bad, as you would do a LOT of updates for potentially related tables.